# Error when using model.predict with tensorflow tutorial. ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have recreated the Tensorflow structured data tutorial on a local jupyter notebook.  This tutorial can be found at https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/feature_columns.

I added the following the get a prediction for new data.

```
x = {
 'age': np.array([1,1]),
 'ca': np.array([1,1]),
 'chol': np.array([1,1]),
 'oldpeak': np.array([1,1]),
 'slope': np.array([1,1]),
 'thalach': np.array([1,1]),
 'trestbps': np.array([1,1]), 
 'sex': np.array([1,1]), 
 'restecg': np.array([1,1]),
 'cp': np.array([1,1]), 
 'exang': np.array([1,1]), 
 'fbs': np.array([1,1]),
 'thal': np.array(['fixed','fixed'])
  }

model.predict(x)
```

which successfully provides 2 predictions.

> array([[0.1833743],[0.1833743]], dtype=float32)

However I cannot use this same dict to make a prediction from the saved model.  I've save the model with

```
model.save('tf_tutorial_2020_05_15/test_1')
```

In a new notebook I have the following code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import feature_column
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('tf_tutorial_2020_05_15/test_1')

x = {
 'age': np.array([1,1]),
 'ca': np.array([1,1]),
 'chol': np.array([1,1]),
 'oldpeak': np.array([1,1]),
 'slope': np.array([1,1]),
 'thalach': np.array([1,1]),
 'trestbps': np.array([1,1]), 
 'sex': np.array([1,1]), 
 'restecg': np.array([1,1]),
 'cp': np.array([1,1]), 
 'exang': np.array([1,1]), 
 'fbs': np.array([1,1]),
 'thal': np.array(['fixed','fixed'])
  }

new_model.predict(x)
```

This throws the error below.  What structure do I need to pass to new_model.predict() to get a prediction? or is there something else I'm doing wrong with this?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-26ee037cb00c> in <module>
     15   }
     16 
---> 17 new_model.predict(x)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1011         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
   1012         workers=workers,
-> 1013         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
   1014 
   1015   def reset_metrics(self):

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in predict(self, model, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    496         model, ModeKeys.PREDICT, x=x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose,
    497         steps=steps, callbacks=callbacks, max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
--> 498         workers=workers, use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    499 
    500 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in _model_iteration(self, model, mode, x, y, batch_size, verbose, sample_weight, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    424           max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    425           workers=workers,
--> 426           use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    427       total_samples = _get_total_number_of_samples(adapter)
    428       use_sample = total_samples is not None

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in _process_inputs(model, mode, x, y, batch_size, epochs, sample_weights, class_weights, shuffle, steps, distribution_strategy, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
    644     standardize_function = None
    645     x, y, sample_weights = standardize(
--> 646         x, y, sample_weight=sample_weights)
    647   elif adapter_cls is data_adapter.ListsOfScalarsDataAdapter:
    648     standardize_function = standardize

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, steps, validation_split, shuffle, extract_tensors_from_dataset)
   2344     # First, we build the model on the fly if necessary.
   2345     if not self.inputs:
-> 2346       all_inputs, y_input, dict_inputs = self._build_model_with_inputs(x, y)
   2347       is_build_called = True
   2348     else:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in _build_model_with_inputs(self, inputs, targets)
   2570     else:
   2571       cast_inputs = inputs
-> 2572     self._set_inputs(cast_inputs)
   2573     return processed_inputs, targets, is_dict_inputs
   2574 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in _set_inputs(self, inputs, outputs, training)
   2657           kwargs['training'] = training
   2658       try:
-> 2659         outputs = self(inputs, **kwargs)
   2660       except NotImplementedError:
   2661         # This Model or a submodel is dynamic and hasn't overridden

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    771                     not base_layer_utils.is_in_eager_or_tf_function()):
    772                   with auto_control_deps.AutomaticControlDependencies() as acd:
--> 773                     outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    774                     # Wrap Tensors in `outputs` in `tf.identity` to avoid
    775                     # circular dependencies.

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/sequential.py in call(self, inputs, training, mask)
    279         kwargs['training'] = training
    280 
--> 281       outputs = layer(inputs, **kwargs)
    282 
    283       # `outputs` will be the inputs to the next layer.

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    771                     not base_layer_utils.is_in_eager_or_tf_function()):
    772                   with auto_control_deps.AutomaticControlDependencies() as acd:
--> 773                     outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    774                     # Wrap Tensors in `outputs` in `tf.identity` to avoid
    775                     # circular dependencies.

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/utils.py in return_outputs_and_add_losses(*args, **kwargs)
     57     inputs = args[inputs_arg_index]
     58     args = args[inputs_arg_index + 1:]
---> 59     outputs, losses = fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
     60     layer.add_loss(losses, inputs)
     61     return outputs

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    566         xla_context.Exit()
    567     else:
--> 568       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    569 
    570     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    613       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    614       initializers = []
--> 615       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    616     finally:
    617       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    495     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    496         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 497             *args, **kwds))
    498 
    499     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2387       args, kwargs = None, None
   2388     with self._lock:
-> 2389       graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2390     return graph_function
   2391 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   2701 
   2702       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 2703       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   2704       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   2705       return graph_function, args, kwargs

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   2591             arg_names=arg_names,
   2592             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 2593             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   2594         self._function_attributes,
   2595         # Tell the ConcreteFunction to clean up its graph once it goes out of

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    976                                           converted_func)
    977 
--> 978       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    979 
    980       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    437         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    438         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 439         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    440     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    441 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/function_deserialization.py in restored_function_body(*args, **kwargs)
    260         .format(_pretty_format_positional(args), kwargs,
    261                 len(saved_function.concrete_functions),
--> 262                 "\n\n".join(signature_descriptions)))
    263 
    264   concrete_function_objects = []

ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
  Positional arguments (2 total):
    * {'age': <tf.Tensor 'features:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>, 'ca': <tf.Tensor 'features_1:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>, 'chol': <tf.Tensor 'features_2:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>, 'cp': <tf.Tensor 'features_3:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>, 'exang': <tf.Tensor 'features_4:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>, 'fbs': <tf.Tensor 'features_5:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>, 'oldpeak': <tf.Tensor 'features_6:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>, 'restecg': <tf.Tensor 'features_7:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>, 'sex': <tf.Tensor 'features_8:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>, 'slope': <tf.Tensor 'features_9:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>, 'thal': <tf.Tensor 'features_10:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=string>, 'thalach': <tf.Tensor 'features_11:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>, 'trestbps': <tf.Tensor 'features_12:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>}
    * None
  Keyword arguments: {}

Expected these arguments to match one of the following 1 option(s):

Option 1:
  Positional arguments (2 total):
    * {'ca': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.int32, name='features/ca'), 'exang': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.int32, name='features/exang'), 'fbs': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.int32, name='features/fbs'), 'chol': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.int32, name='features/chol'), 'thalach': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.int32, name='features/thalach'), 'thal': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.string, name='features/thal'), 'cp': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.int32, name='features/cp'), 'age': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.int32, name='features/age'), 'oldpeak': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='features/oldpeak'), 'restecg': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.int32, name='features/restecg'), 'trestbps': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.int32, name='features/trestbps'), 'slope': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.int32, name='features/slope'), 'sex': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.int32, name='features/sex')}
    * None
  Keyword arguments: {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip uninstall tensorboard
pip install -q tf-nightly
pip install --ignore-installed tf-nightly
```

Should fix the issue.